# clickable buttons on headings

Tags: org-mode, outline, margins

Emacs shows clickable buttons when visiting NEWS (`C-h n`):

[image]

This is controlled by `outline-minor-mode-use-buttons`.

How to make Org do the same thing?

Comment: Without enabling outline minor mode in Org, otherwise I won’t ask this question.

Comment: Implementing it by hand is OK. But it's better to use an existing Org feature/function.